# Using getline and stringstream to check if words in a sentence are in a file

Tags: c++, file, parsing, getline, istringstream

I've been working on an assignment for days and I can't seem to figure this out.

I have been given 4 files with words in them (adjectives, nouns, pronouns, and verbs) and I have to check a user inputted sentence and determine the structure of the sentence and whether or not the different types of words occur in a certain order.

My approach was to use getline to get the sentence and then use istringstream to look at each individual word in the sentence and compare each word to each file.

For example: I would get the first word, loop through the adjectives file and determine if it were an adjective. If not, then I would look at the same word and loop through the nouns file and determine if it were a noun, and so on and so forth.

I cannot used arrays, vectors, or string functions for this assignment. This is really throwing me off. I would like to use istringstream to look at each individual word in the sentence but I can't seem to get that to work.

For example: After looking at the first word and determining whether it is an adjective, noun, pronoun, or verb I want to them use istringstream to look at the second word in the sentence and so on and so forth. This isn't working and I'm not sure why.

After I get this working I plan on putting each word into a boolean function i.e. check if the first word is a adjective, noun, pronoun, or verb and return true depending on which it is.

I'm a beginner to C++ and I'm going nuts trying to make this work. Is there a better approach for this? What's wrong with what I'm trying to do? Here's what I have thus far:

```
  string sentence;
  string fileWord;

  cout << "Input your sentence : " << endl;
  getline(cin, sentence);

  stringstream iss(sentence);

  string firstWord;
  string secondWord;


 ifstream adjectiveFile;
 adjectiveFile.open("/words/adjectives");

  // Outputs error if there's an error opening the file
  if(adjectiveFile.fail()){
    cout << "Failed to open file" << endl;
    exit(1);
  }

  // Opens noun file
  ifstream nounFile;
  nounFile.open("/words/nouns");

  // Outputs error if there's an error opening the file
  if(nounFile.fail()){
    cout << "Failed to open noun file" << endl;
    exit(1);
  }

  // Opens pronouns file
  ifstream pronounFile;
  pronounFile.open("/words/pronouns");

  // Outputs error if there's an error opening the file
  if(pronounFile.fail()){
    cout << " Failed to open pronoun file" << endl;
    exit(1);
  }

  // Opens verbs file
  ifstream verbFile;
  verbFile.open("/words/verbs");

// Outputs error if there's an error opening the file
  if(verbFile.fail()){
    cout << "Failed to open verb file" << endl;
    exit(1);
  }

// Gets first word from sentence and them determines what type of word   it is by looping through each file
iss >> firstWord;

  while (adjectiveFile >> fileWord) {
    if (firstWord == fileWord) {
        cout << "The first word of the sentence is the adjective " << firstWord << endl;
    }
  }

  while(nounFile >> fileWord){
    if(firstWord == fileWord){
        cout << "The first word of the sentence is the noun " << firstWord << endl;
    }
  }

  while(pronounFile >> fileWord){
    if(firstWord == fileWord){
        cout << "The first word of the sentence is the pronoun " << firstWord << endl;
    }
  }

  while(verbFile >> fileWord){
    if(firstWord == fileWord){
        cout << "The first word of the sentence is the verb " << firstWord << endl;
    }
  }


// Doesn't work. Can't access the second word of the sentence using istringstream. 
iss >> secondWord;

  while(adjectiveFile >> fileWord){
    if(secondWord == fileWord){
        cout << "The second word of the sentence is the adjective " << secondWord << endl;
    }
  }

  while(nounFile >> fileWord){
    if(secondWord == fileWord){
        cout << "The second word of the sentence is the noun " << secondWord << endl;
    }
  }

  while(pronounFile >> fileWord){
    if(secondWord == fileWord){
        cout << "The second word of the sentence is the pronoun " << secondWord << endl;
    }
  }

  while(verbFile >> fileWord){
    if(secondWord == fileWord){
        cout << "The second word of the sentence is the verb " << secondWord << endl;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid that there's some misunderstanding. You've got this "What's wrong with what I'm trying to do?" thing completely backwards. It should be the other way around. You are the one that needs to explain what's wrong with the code, and how it should work differently, and what exactly you can't figure out. stackoverflow.com is not the "guess what's wrong with this code" kind of a website. P.S. Do you really expect to cut-and-paste and duplicate the same chunk of code for the third word? Do you really believe that this is the right approach?

Comment: I mean why can't I access the second word of the sentence using istringstream.

Comment: "can't I access" is not a useful problem description. It's like telling a car mechanic that you car "does not move", and expect him to understand what the problem is.

Comment: A car mechanic is _paid for the solution_...That's somehow different.

Answer (score 1):

You’re trying to read the same file more than once. After the first time that you run `while(adjectiveFile >> fileWord){}` the pointer will be at the end of file, so the next time you try to call the same loop, `adjectiveFile >> fileWord` will fail and you never actually get to check if `secondWord == fileWord`.

You could look into`ifstream::seekg()` and  `ifstream::clear()` to see how to read it twice. Having said that, and as mentioned in the comments above, copying and pasting the same bit of code 4x is certainly not the best  approach.

Comment: Yeah I was mainly just trying to visualize things. I know it's best to write functions instead of repeating the code over and over again. Thanks for the tip with seekg and clear.